# Makefile recipe changed (gcc to cc, and -D option disappears)

Tags: makefile

I tried adding a rule in a Makefile.inc file which is called by the main Makefile.

```
aarch64/shared/bootcode.s: aarch64/shared/bootcode.S
    gcc -E -DNSG1 $^ > $@
```

But when it is executed, it runs like this.

```
cc -E  aarch64/shared/bootcode.S > aarch64/shared/bootcode.s
```

Why does `gcc` change to `cc` and why does `-DNSG1` disappear?

Comment: What makes you think that that rule is being executed?

Comment: @Beta because after I 'touch' the bootcode.S file, when I do make, the command is printed and the bootcode.s file is newly generated. I can see it.

Comment: What @Beta means is, why do you think _THAT_ rule is being executed?  Surely, some rule is being executed.  But since the recipe being printed by  make is not the recipe for that rule, it's pretty clear that make is executing some OTHER rule and not that one.  In particular, the rule is for the target `aarch64/shared/bootcode.s` which is not the target in your rule.  So you'll have to find out where `aarch64/shared/bootcode.s` is being asked for in your makefile and change it to the target you want instead.

Comment: Short response is, there's not enough information here to help you.  You have provided only the rule you want to execute, but the important thing is not that rule but the rule that lists this target as a prerequisite.  If you can't figure it out I recommend using `make -d` and/or `make --trace` to see what's going on.

Comment: @MadScientist yes, you're right. Definitely the `cc -E` command is not from any Makefile I use and it's coming from a higher implicit rule. The problem is I want to pass a defined variable with the `cc -E` so that part of an assembly code is selected during the preprocessing. And the variable I want to pass using make command argument. Please advise me if you know a good method.

Comment: I don't really understand the question in your comment.  You may need to edit your question and provide full details.  The problem isn't that you need to define your rule properly.  You have defined a rule to build the target `aarch64/ab21q_foo_test/bootcode.s`.  But make wants to build a target `aarch64/shared/bootcode.s`.  Obviously, these are not the same.  _That's_ the problem; you need to either define a rule to build the target make wants to build, or figure out how to get make to build the target you want it to build.  Nothing you've given us here helps us help you with that.

Comment: I tried overriding the implicit rule by place `%.s : %.S
    gcc -E -DINTGRP=$(INTGRP) $< -o $@` and the recipe is executed but the assembly line selection isn't done correctly.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm sorry, I fixed my question.(directory name fix)

Comment: I asked a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379549/preprocessing-for-an-assembly-code-not-working-if-else-endif

Comment: @MadScientist Please write a short answer(implicit rule is in action) so that I can choose it as an answer.