# preprocessing for an assembly code not working (#if #else #endif)

Tags: assembly, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Here is the assembly code bootcode.S

```
        .section boot, "ax", %progbits

get_intid:
        #if INTGRP==NSG1
            #warning taking NSG1
                mrs     x0, s3_0_c12_c12_0
        #else
            #warning taking G0
                mrs     x0, s3_0_c12_c8_0
        #endif
                ret
        .end
```

Now I want to do preprocessing so that according to the variable INTGRP( either NSG1 or G0), corresponding line is selected in the ".S" file and the result is written in ".s" file.
When I try `gcc -E -DINTGRP=G0`, it always selects the second line. Actually it's regardless of the -D option. So how should I give the command so that the #if part becomes true?

ADD:
from the comments, I realized what's wrong.
So the correct method is :

```
        .section boot, "ax", %progbits
#define G0 0
#define NSG1 1

get_intid:
#if INTGRP==NSG1
            #warning taking NSG1
                mrs     x0, s3_0_c12_c12_0
#else
            #warning taking G0
                mrs     x0, s3_0_c12_c8_0
#endif
                ret
        .end
```

and use the command

```
cc -E -DINTGRP=0 bootcode.S -o bootcode.s
```

or

```
cc -E -DINTGRP=1 bootcode.S -o bootcode.s
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where do you expect the used `G0` and `NSG1` to be defined? Please provide a complete [mre]. (different angle on same problem as mentioned by Peter Cordes below)

Comment: `==` is always numeric, not comparing token-names.  Undefined token names evaluate to `0` in `#if` expressions (after expansion of any defined macros).  Looks like a duplicate.

Comment: folks, thanks for the comments. I realized what's wrong and I added #define for G0 and NSG1 and called `cc -E` with the defined value. I'll update the question right away.

Comment: The normal method is a macro like `#ifdef INTGRP_USE_NSG1`, with the other option implicitly being G0.  Fewer lines up setup to make it work.  Magic numbers (0 and 1) in the compiler command line is not better than `-DINTGRP_USE_NSG1` or `-UINTGRP_USE_NSG1` (or nothing).

Comment: Also, for a real build you'd normally just `cc -c -D... foo.S` to preprocess and assemble in one step.  That's the whole point of using capital `.S` filenames.